# How can I redirect to a daughter route by joining my application?

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I have my app-routing-module.ts file, and my web-template.module.ts file,
I need my application to start at 'inicio / list', but list is a daughter route, how can I redirect from the beginning of my application to that route, taking into account that they are two different files.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [{
 path : 'inicio',
 loadChildren : './modules/web-template/web-template.module#WebTemplateModule'
 },{
  path : '**', pathMatch : 'full',
  redirectTo : 'inicio'
}];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

---

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
 import { TemplateComponent } from './template/template.component';
 import { NewsInitComponent } from '../pages/news-init/news-init.component';

  const routes: Routes = [
    { path : '',
      component : TemplateComponent,
      children: [
     {
    path : 'list',
    component : NewsInitComponent
     }
   ]
   }
  ];

  @NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
  })

  export class WebTemplateRoutingModule { }
```

I have tried to redirect from the web-template.module.ts file, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should just redirect to `inicio/list` in the app.module:

```js
  { path : '**', redirectTo : 'inicio/list' } // you don't need pathMatch: 'full' in a catch-all rule
```

In addition I would extend a bit the routing in the web template module, adding an empty rule and a catch-all rule. Like this:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TemplateComponent } from './template/template.component';
import { NewsInitComponent } from '../pages/news-init/news-init.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component : TemplateComponent,
    children: [
      { path : 'list', component : NewsInitComponent },
      // this will redirect '/inicio' to `inicio/list`
      { path : '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full' },
      // this will redirect '/inicio/nonexistint' to `inicio/list`
      { path : '**', redirectTo: 'list' }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule] // I don't think you need to export this.
})
export class WebTemplateRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: @JoaquinHernandez what _exactly_ don't work means? What did you wrote on the address bar? What do you get after the routing? Do you have any errors on the console? You should explain your problem with as much detail as you can

Comment: The main redirection of the application to the daughter route, there is no console error, it simply does not have a module to load so I discovered that it did not load any route, so in the answer below it was what I proceeded to do and it worked as it did I needed, the answer you gave me helped me a lot, and with that I could solve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is my app-routing.module.ts and the second code, is my web-template-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [{
  path : 'inicio',
  loadChildren : './modules/web-template/web-template.module#WebTemplateModule'
},{
  path : '**', redirectTo: 'inicio' 
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule] 
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

---

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TemplateComponent } from './template/template.component';
import { NewsInitComponent } from '../pages/news-init/news-init.component';
import { NewDetailComponent } from '../pages/new-detail/new-detail.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component : TemplateComponent,
  children: [
    { path : 'noticias', component : NewsInitComponent },
    { path : 'noticias/detalle', component : NewDetailComponent },
    // this will redirect '/inicio' to `inicio/list`
    { path : '', redirectTo: 'noticias', pathMatch: 'full' },
    // this will redirect '/inicio/nonexistint' to `inicio/list`
    { path : '**', redirectTo: 'noticias' }
  ]
 }
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class WebTemplateRoutingModule { }
```

In conclusion, the first thing you have to do is load the module of the daughter routes in the app-routing.module, with a main redirection, once the module is loaded with the daughter routes, you do another redirection to load the route daughter this in the file we-template-routing.module.ts